# Highcharts scatter chart with a name per point

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to tweak a Highcharts scatter plot with this date series

```
series: [{
    data: [[1,2],[2,5]]
}]
```

so that i can put a name on each point, I want to show the name in the tooltip. 
The [API doc says](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data) an object of named values can be defined like this

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        name: 'Point 1',
        x: 1,
        y: 2
    }, {
        name: 'Point 2',
        x: 2,
        y: 5
    }]
}]
```

but it seems the x and y values are not picked up. See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paultoconnell/TkMjZ/6/) example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point), the name field is the name of the point as shown in the legend, tooltip, dataLabel, and so on. I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkMjZ/17/) to include the highcharts library, and I am seeing this behaviour (i.e. if I hover over a point, its label is displayed).

If you want the x-axis labels set correctly, you need to ensure that the `xAxis` section of your chart configuration does not have a `categories` key.

Comment: Your fiddle is not working for me. It just shows "Series 1" on both points. Perhaps an update to Highcharts library broke the desired behavior?

Comment: maybe it worked before, but the fiddle no longer works - it is back to using the series name, NOT the point name, as the name of the point.

Answer (score 6):

This answer works for Highcharts 4.1.9.

Took me a long time to figure out hence I want to pass it on in case someone is looking for this as well.

Your mileage may vary for other versions.

```
       plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                dataLabels: {
                    format: "{point.name}",
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Projects',
            data: [{"name":"Point 1", "x":1,"y":2}, {"name":"Point 2", "x":4,"y":5}]
        }]
```

**What are the key points?**

1. Ensure that the scatter.dataLabels is enabled and the format is `{point.name}`
2. Ensure that the data is in the format of `{"name":"Point 1", "x":1,"y":2}`

Comment: {point.key} instead of {point.name} is working here: tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name} ({point.key})</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x}, {point.y} '
            }

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551689/highcharts-scatter-chart-with-a-name-per-point#comment59457651_33037638), what works for me in Highcharts 5.0.6 is:

```ts
{
  type: 'scatter',
  tooltip: { headerFormat: '<strong>{point.key}</strong><br>' },
  data: [{ x: 0, y: 1, name: 'Whatever' }, ...]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also show names in the legend section. Updated the selected answer above [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kentaguilar/eK54U/)

```
series: [{
        name: 'Point 1',
        data: [[3, 3]]
    }, {
        name: 'Point 2',
        data: [[4, 8]]
    }, {
        name: 'Point 3',
        data: [[9, 15]]
    }]
```

Comment: this seems to be the only answer that actually answers the original question!

Comment: yeah this one is straight to the point solution to the question

Answer (score 3):

This is a new feature in HighCharts 3.0. You have to define the xAxis type to 'Category' and give the name of the point in the data if you want it to appear on the xAxis:

```
 xAxis: {
   //categories: ['Green', 'Pink'],
    type: 'category'
},
...
 data: [{
        name: 'Green',
        x: 1,
        y: 2
    }, {
        name: 'Pink',
        x: 2,
        y: 5
    }]
```

See your jsFiddle code updated :[here](http://jsfiddle.net/TkMjZ/214/).
Note that I have added the tooltip formating feature to show that point.x has no more meaning in this context, only point.name remains relevant.
 Also, you cannot have two points with different 'name' at the same x position.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this issue and after finding the solution in the documentation I must say the behavior as designed feels a bit unexpected.

Per the docs (here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.tooltip), the tooltip does not show all fields you can add to a data point, but rather

`Defaults to x: <b>{point.x}</b><br/>y: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>.`

To show the data point name (and any other fields you want to), simply change the HTML rendered by the tooltip. For example, you can display the point name and coordinates in the tooltip while removing the series name as follows:

```
chart: {
  type: "scatter",
}
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: '',
  pointFormat: 'Name: <b>{point.name}</b><br/>Load time: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>Requests: <b>{point.x}</b>',
},
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer - it seems to be some kind of change in the highcharts API since 2013.